# Change collision properties of multiple existing physics bodies in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics, collision

In Corona SDK, I have a curved LineObject with which I need other objects to be able to collide.  To achieve this, I am creating a large number (hundreds) of small circular physics bodies along this curved line (like a string of pearls).

The physical interaction (collisions) between the line (the "pearls") and other objects needs to change at runtime. Since it is not possible to modify collision filters at runtime, is there a way to do this without displaying all the circles again from scratch, which would affect performance?

Comment: This question isn't really answerable as it. What do you when you say they share physical properties? What's a collisionFilter? Are you using some library with Lua bindings? Also StackOverflow is better suited for questions that have specific answers - it's less suited for general brainstorming.

Comment: i just mean the filter. i'm using Corona SDK

Comment: When you say "group of objects", do you mean you are using the `groupIndex` parameter in the collision filter?

Comment: I mean creating an object in wich i ":insert" all the others

Comment: I see.  No, each physics body needs to have the collision filter parameter set when you declare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No Changes To Collision Filter

As you say, you **cannot** change the collision filter parameter on a physics body once it has been created.  To clarify what this means, consider this example of the use of the filter from the Corona SDK [documentation on Collisions](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#collision-filtering) (which also explains very well the use of `categoryBits` and `maskBits`):

```
local floorCollisionFilter = { categoryBits=1, maskBits=6 }
local floor = display.newRect( 0, 0, 320, 80 )
physics.addBody( floor, "static", { filter=floorCollisionFilter } )
```

After the physics body is instantiated, changes to `floorCollisionFilter` will have no effect on the collision properties of `floor`.

## Precollision Detection

You can, however, change the collision behaviour of objects using **preCollision detection**.  If you have a preCollision listener on your objects, you can determine if they should be involved in the collision event that is being triggered and set the `event.contact.isEnabled = false` if they should not.  There are gotchas: this can be costly if you have many physics bodies and the precollision calls can be noisy (many possible calls per collision event).

## Multi-Element Body and `isBodyActive` Property

Maybe you should reconsider how you are adding physics to the curved line.  You say you are placing many circles along a path (like a string of beads/pearls) to detect collisions between that path and other bodies. If the shape of the path does not need to change, you should consider using an [edge shape (chain) body](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.html#multi-element-bodies).  There do not seem to be limitations on the number of vertices used in creating it or convexity requirements (unlike polygonal bodies).

This would allow you to remove the edge shape body (assume it is called `object`) from the simulation (other bodies will ignore/pass through it) by setting `object.isBodyActive = false`. This won't remove the object from the display and you can always set `isBodyActive = true` later.  See the documentation for gotchas about changing physics body properties (i.e. you need to use small delays).

One last note about the use of the edge shape body.  Even if the shape of the path **did** need to change in a controlled way, you might get better performance destroying the existing edge body and creating a new one along the new path rather than moving around a huge number of little circular bodies.

Comment: The precollision solution could work.  It depends on how many objects you are talking about.

Comment: I used a lot of circles to handle physics on a curved line. So i'm talking about hudreds of them

Comment: I sometimes need the curve to collide with a moving object and other times to be fully permeable.

Comment: @Sincizio Can you edit your question to include this information and explain why a multi-element physics body can't be used (for example, is the curve changing shape?)

Comment: @Sincizio Are you using a string of pearls so the curve can change shape?

Comment: my problem is that those points are created one after another so i don't know if it's possible to include them all in a multi-element object

Comment: You don't know the shape of the curve initially?  The curve is growing?

Comment: So you are adding the circular bodies as the curve path grows?

Comment: the shape is defined by an equation more or less. it is all created in one step (a for loop to define its points). no not growing. but the process of creating it is iterative. i don't know other ways to do so actually

Comment: You have a parametrized equation of a curve that you are using to generate a set of points.  Once the points are generated, you can use them to make an edge shape body.

Comment: i knew that could be done with less than 8 vertices. am i wrong?

Comment: sorry i was thinking about poligonal obj

Comment: Edge shapes don't have some of the constraints of polygons.  I'm not sure about the number of vertices.

Comment: In the documentation, the example of the edge body has 10 vertices.

Comment: i'll let you know if it is possible then!

Comment: Great.  Please accept the answer of this works.  Good luck!